# Restrict apps to iPhone-only when submit

Tags: iphone, ipad, device

I restrict the app to run on iPhones only by setting in General tab of target setting as following:
[image]

I see nowhere in the itunes connect to set the devices type.

In **Testflight** app where I can install and test my app, I still see the following line, indicating that my app can run on iPad:

> "Compatibility: Requires iOS 7.0 or later. Compatible with iPod touch,
>   iPhone and iPad".

I know that iPad can run my app (not in full screen), but I want to make sure: Is this normal?

Comment: IPhone apps will run on an iPad but they won't take advantage of the full screen. They will either appear a small image in the centre of the screen or can be zoomed to full screen by magnifying each pixel. What you see is normal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's normal. An iPad can run an iPhone app, if the iPad meets all of the hardware requirements of the app. (You can specify the hardware requirements using the [`UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` key in your app's `Info.plist`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html)).

The [app store review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#functionality) don't require that your app runs on an iPad (although it is encouraged):

> **2.4.1** To ensure people get the most out of your app, iPhone apps should run on iPad whenever possible. We encourage you to consider building universal apps so customers can use them on all of their devices.